# Convert string to type in object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The code I have to implement takes a posted list of data from an Ajax call from a web page.

I know the object I need to update, but each field/value pair is coming through as string values and not as their proper types.

So I am trying to work out the type of the property, casting the value as the new type and then apply that to the field using reflection.

However I am getting the following error for anything other than strings.

```
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.TimeSpan'.
```

The code I am attempting the conversion in is;

```
    public void Update<T>(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(fieldName);
        Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

        var a = Convert.ChangeType(fieldValue, propertyType);
    }
```

So  is the target object.

Comment: Your error is saying there's no native conversion to from string to timespan, that method isn't capable of doing it. I would recommend looking over the timespan docs and trying to come up with a clever way to do the conversion.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use ASP.NET MVC's model-binding? (Or is this not an MVC project?)

Comment: It's not just TimeSpan.  It's everything.  I can't convert from string to int, timespan etc.

Comment: it is an MVC app yeah but i am passed a json object of fieldname, value and id.  i need to find the object, and then set the property of that field.  the ui is a bunch of li elements and the text of each is what is passed to me.

Comment: As you are mentioning that you are receiving Json values, in this case can we use `JObject.Parse(jsonValue).ToObject<FooBarType>()` here. Any views on this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no absolute answer that works for all types. But, you could use a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) instead of Convert, it usually works better. For example, there is a [TimeSpanConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.timespanconverter.aspx):

```
public void Update<T>(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(fieldName);
    Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
    if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
    {
        var a = converter.ConvertFrom(fieldValue, type);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: that is a great solution.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `Convert` the type need to be `IConvertible`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)

> ```
>  For the conversion to succeed, value must implement the IConvertible interface
> ```

[TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) doesn't implement it ...

So you can check before calling `Convert` or add `try{} catch{}`

Answer (score 2):

For handling JSON in MVC (and .NET in general) I use JSON.NET. It is included out-of-the-box in the ASP.NET MVC 4 project template and available on NuGet otherwise. Deserializing JSON string content is (generally) as simple as:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(json);
```

If the JSON being passed isn't a serialized model, you could create a code model to match the JSON.

If that doesn't work for your scenario, you can try the `Convert` class which has options for conversion if you know the type:

```
Convert.ToInt32(stringValue);
```

Or the `ChangeType` method if it's dynamic:

```
Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType);
```